# Simple button click example with Ajax and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am new to both Ajax and Node.js + Express. At this point I am trying to figure out how to communicate with both the front and back end through buttons.

I have a button on an HTML page which I would like to use to call a function from the backend and output text to the client.

Here is what I've pieced together for what I need but I am looking for an example on how this could be done.

*This is all happening on /page*

**index.hjs file**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="install()">Install</button>

// Client Side Ajax Script
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {
        $.post('/page', {data: 'blah'}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }, 'json');
</script>
```

**app.js file**

```
app.post('/page', function (req, res, next) {
  calling.aFunction();
  res.write('A message!');
});
```

Are these all the parts that I need and what needs to be edited to get this functionality to work?

Comment: Yeah I've tried it and received the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: install is not defined`

Comment: That is beacuse your `onclick` attribute in the `button` element has some method `install()` listed you don't seem to need this since you assign a click event handler using jQuery

Comment: Removing the install() method/function doesn't seem to fix the issue. The error is gone now but not getting any output or anything.

Comment: I don't know what issue you are reffering to, you only asked if this is how you do it.  Do you have an error that should be included? Have you checked your network monitor to see if the `POST` method is completing?

Comment: Verify in your console the request goes thru - check your node console for errors.

Comment: Use `res.send('A message!')` in order to output the text in the browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

index.js

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Install</button>

// Client Side Ajax Script
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {
        $.post('/page', {data: 'blah'}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }, 'json');
</script>
```

app.js

```
app.post('/page', function (req, res) {
    calling.aFunction();
    res.send('A message!');
});
```

You should see "A message!" in the browser console.

Comment: And how do I get the 'blah' data in app.js?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "blah" data. That's just my way of showing the payload being sent to the post destination

Comment: Sorry, I had to be more specific in my question: If I would like to also pass back data from index.js to the backend (app.js) with the $.post method how would I do that? Isn't that {data: 'blah'} ? And in app.post(... how would I read it, from req?

Comment: req.body.data would be "blah"

Comment: Btw, my last comment assumes you are using express-bodyparser to process POST data