# How can I execute selenium node js script from other js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created files as per following:

**Demo.js**

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');     

var driver = new webdriver
    .Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('simple programmer');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnK')).click();
driver.quit();
```

**Run.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express(); 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<button type="button" onclick="test();">Run Script</button>');
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});

function test() {
    var fork = require('child_process').fork;
    var child = fork('./Demo');
}
```

What I want to do is :

1. When I run file `Run.js`, it has button called "Run script".
2. As soon as I click on that button, It should run automation script which is stored in `Demo.js`.

Currently for me above test function is not working and unable to run `Demo.js` on click of button.

**Error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the function `test` on the client side, but the function is defined on the server side.

You could create a form on the client side which would send a post request to the server upon click. Then handle the `POST` request on the server side to execute the desired code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send(
    '<form action="/run" method="POST">' +
    '  <input type="submit" name="run" value="Run Script" />' +
    '</form>');
});

app.post('/run', function (req, res) {
  var fork = require('child_process').fork;
  var child = fork('./Demo');
  res.send('done');
});
```

You could also send the `POST` request with an Ajax request on the client side:
[Simple button click example with Ajax and Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158186/simple-button-click-example-with-ajax-and-node-js)